# Is there any open-source code we can get for something similar to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, source-code, open-source

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SO Clones?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/so-clones)

I've found that source code of http://stackoverflow.com is not open-source. What similar apps are there that have source code available?

Comment: Check this out, open source in php and MongoDB, very fast! http://support.lampcms.com

Answer (score 4):

http://code.google.com/p/cnprog/

They practically "forked" the initial version of SO and from there created a Django based version which is open source.

Saying it was "forked" is a decent way to say they copied everything that was public on SO site and make it theirs ( how is that called in english?? .. oohh yeap.. stoo... stol. stolll.. oh I forgot )

Answer (score 1):

There is one that was created called [Knowledge Exchange](http://knowledgeexchange.codeplex.com/). There was another called 'Stacked' but their page appears to be down, so I don't know the status of that project.

Answer (score -3):

When you get down to it, StackOverflow is a forum, of which there are many open source variants. Not as aimed at Q&A, not as slick, but the basic technologies are there.

Comment: That's like saying "when you get right down to it, a Ferrari is just a transportation device. A sickly donkey should get you mostly there."

Comment: Replace the donkey with a rusty motorbike, and sure. Studying it you'd see how everything worked, how the wheel turns with an axis, and if you look hard enough how an internal combustion engine works. To then build a Ferrari with that information is possible, if difficult.

Comment: The world would be so complicated without analogies.

Comment: I love the way everybody is assuming I'm insulting SO here.

Comment: @Rex M: That was an awesome analogy :)