# Is the stackoverflow platform open source?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [StackOverFlow Platform](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39470/stackoverflow-platform)
>   [The StackOverflow Source Code?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14656/the-stackoverflow-source-code)
>   [Install stackoverflow like software on my site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42613/install-stackoverflow-like-software-on-my-site)
>   [Is there any open source code we can get similar to stackoverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30269/is-there-any-open-source-code-we-can-get-similar-to-stackoverflow)

The StackOverflow's site could be re-used in many different ways for different purposes.

Is it an open source project? Can I build my own instance of it?

Comment: This belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: It's not open source (but could be someday).  The closest you're going to get is http://stackexchange.com/

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14656/the-stackoverflow-source-code

Comment: This was hilarious brutal answer.. [closed] :D