# Where can I download the software that runs Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [The StackOverflow Source Code?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14656/the-stackoverflow-source-code)
>   [Is the stackoverflow engine available?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16054/is-the-stackoverflow-engine-available)

Where can I download the software used for Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is StackOverflow Platform OpenSource?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42713/is-stackoverflow-platform-opensource), [Is the stackoverflow engine available?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16054/is-the-stackoverflow-engine-available) and [Stack Overflow Clones?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't, it's privately owned.

Answer (score 3):

There have [been discussions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14656/the-stackoverflow-source-code) to make the code open source, but that's currently not the case.